# Expected number of rounds played in a game

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose one plays the following game: Start with $n$ rounds. Each round, flip a weighted coin with probability $p$ of coming up heads. Each time we obtain heads, we get $m$ additional rounds added to our current total. We play until we run out of rounds.
The expected number of rounds played is:
$$
E[\# Rounds]= n + nmp + n(mp)^2 + n(mp)^3 +\dots 
$$
My question is how does one derive this expectation formula?
(This is a question for work, not school).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of [branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process). At the beginning, we have $Z_0=n$ individuals. At the first step, each individual produces $X_{0,i}$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) offsprings where $\mathbb P(X_{0,i}=m)=p$, $\mathbb P(X_{0,i}=0)=1-p$ and $X_{0,i}$ are independent. After the first step we have 
$$
Z_1=\sum_{i=1}^{Z_0=n} X_{0,i}, \quad \mathbb E[Z_1]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_{0,i}] 
=n\mathbb E[X_{0,1}]=nmp.$$
At the next step, we have random number $Z_1$ of individuals. Each of them produces $X_{1,i}$ ($i=1,\ldots,Z_1$) offsprings where $\mathbb P(X_{1,i}=m)=p$, $\mathbb P(X_{1,i}=0)=1-p$ and $X_{1,i}$ are independent and do not depend on $Z_1$. After the second step we have 
$$
Z_2=\sum_{i=1}^{Z_1} X_{1,i}.
$$
To calculate mean value of $Z_2$ we need [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)
$$
\mathbb E[Z_2]=\mathbb E[Z_1] \cdot \mathbb E[X_{1,1}] 
=nmp\cdot mp=n(mp)^2.$$
Next, 
$$
Z_3=\sum_{i=1}^{Z_2} X_{2,i}, \quad \mathbb E[Z_3]=\mathbb E[Z_2] \cdot \mathbb E[X_{2,1}] =n(mp)^2\cdot mp=n(mp)^3
$$
and so on. 
To get total expected number of individuals we need to sum up the infinite series
$$
\mathbb E[Z_0+Z_1+Z_2+\ldots] = n+nmp+n(mp)^2+n(mp)^3+\ldots
$$

Comment: Marked this as the answer due to it being most rigorous. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4):

The expected number of added rounds won when playing 1 round is mp, so the expected number of added rounds won when playing x rounds is xmp.

E[#rounds] is the initial number of rounds (a=n), plus the expected number of rounds added when playing the initial a rounds (b=amp=nmp), plus the expected number of rounds added when playing the additional b rounds (c=bmp=n(mp)^2), plus the expected number of rounds added when playing the additional c rounds (d=cmp=n(mp)^3), etc.

Comment: @Leucippus It is a perfectly valid and clear answer to the question.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis There are no $b$ rounds added. Here $b$ is the expectation of  random number of rounds, not the number of rounds itself. So it is not explained why the expected number of additional rounds is $c=bmp$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, just some hints how to deduce the formula without resorting to some deep theories (this is similar in spirit to @Kevin's answer).

First you have to show that expected number $E_n$ of rounds is finite iff $mp<1$; there are several ways to do this (including the one given below for the computation of expectation).

Then you should observe that $E_n$ depends linearly on the initial number of rounds, i.e. $E_n = n E_1$.

Finally, conditioning on the first toss and using the law of total expectation,
$$
E_1 = 1+ p \cdot E_m + (1-p)\cdot 0  = 1+ p \cdot mE_1
$$
(one toss plus the expected value if we get heads times the probability of getting a head plus the expected value if we get tails time the probability of tails).

Hence, for $mp<1$ (the finiteness of expectation is essential!),
$$
E_1 = \frac{1}{1-mp}.
$$